# Are the number of infinities countable or uncountable?

Tags: cardinals

We have $\aleph_0$, $\aleph_1$, and so on. But why wouldn't there be an $\aleph_\pi$, for example? What is the proof that the types of infinities are a countable set?

Comment: See the definition of Aleph numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number

Answer (score 5):

The cardinalities are $\aleph_\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is an ordinal. So you can have $\aleph_\omega$ (which is the least cardinality larger than $\aleph_0,\aleph_1,\aleph_2,\ldots)$ or even $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ or more. So there are uncountably many, but not because they are indexed by reals, but because there is a proper class of them (i.e. too many to be a set of any size, let alone a countable one).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry if it's a dumb question, but couldn't there be a mapping from $(0, 1)$ to the $\aleph_\alpha$? (For example, $\aleph_1$ would map to $0.1$, $\aleph_{\aleph_2}$  would map to $0.02$ )

Comment: If you map $\aleph_0$ to $a\in(0,1)$, where would you map $\aleph_1$?  Note that this is the smallest cardinal larger than $\aleph_0$ so if you want an order isomorphism, you'd need a smallest real number larger than $a$ which doesn't exist...  If you dont care about the order, you could do that (not for all cardinals but for the first $2^\omega$ many).

Comment: @JessicaSinger Like fweth said, since the ordinals are well-ordered you can't map $(0,1)$ to the ordinals in an order preserving way. But even if you wellordered $(0,1)=\{r_\beta:\beta<2^{\aleph_0}\}$, and mapped $r_\beta$ to a cardinal $\aleph_{\alpha_\beta}$, then you still have a set of cardinals. The union is a cardinal, and then there must be a cardinal bigger than that. 

The basic idea is that if you have collection of cardinals indexed by a set, then the union is a cardinal, which has a successor. This is also why the collection of cardinals is not itself a set.

Comment: @FrancisAdams Incidentally--and at risk of causing more confusion than it's worth--a fun fact is that in the absence of the axiom of choice, it's consistent that there is an order-embedding of $(0,1)$ into the *cardinals*. (The non-well-ordered cardinals, of course... not into the $\aleph$'s.)